# Keeping an object var as Object when referencing to it

Tags: c#

I have to take this to a program that can handle a Double linked list, but I am very new to C# and windows forms. I have the following code so far.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace doublelinkedtest
{
    public class nodetoDBList
    {
        public object elements;
        public nodetoDBList prev;
        public nodetoDBList next;

        public nodetoDBList (int temp)
        {
            elements = temp;
            next = null;
        }

        public void inserToList(object elements)
        {
            nodetoDBList newLink;
            newLink = new nodetoDBList (elements);
        }
    }
}
```

But now I get the following error:
Argument 1: Cannot convert from 'object' to 'int'.
Why do I get this error?. I am only referencing the variable, I am not converting it.

I am very new to C#. And as you can see I am taking this project step by step in order to achieve a double linked list project. Please Help!.

Comment: either change the method signature to accept `object` as a parameter or cast temp as `(int)temp` or use the  `this.elements = Convert.ToInt32(temp);`

Comment: Why the downvote? I made a completely valid question -.-"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling the `nodeToDBList` constructor (which takes an `int`) with an object instead:

```
public nodetoDBList (int temp) <- Constructor takes an int
{
    elements = temp;
    next = null;
}

public void inserToList(object elements)
{
    nodetoDBList newLink;
    newLink = new nodetoDBList (elements); <- passing in an object instead
}
```

Since `elements` is declared as an `object`, and it's an `object` in the `insertToList` method, odds are you should modify the constructor so that `temp` is an `object` instead of an `int`.

Comment: The constructor shouldn't be taking an `int` anyway. The field takes an `object`.

Comment: @siride - yes, I was just updating my answer to state that as well.

Comment: But when I make elements = temp, that automatically converts elements to int? how so?

Comment: because obeject{int} is the type ..assuming you use the debugger and QuickWatch to inspect the variable type.

Comment: @CrisAlfie - the program wouldn't be really *converting* `elements` to an `int`; it would essentially be saying "all I know about `elements` is that it's an `object`" even though it's really an `int` behind the scenes. If you try to act on `elements` in code, you can treat it like an `object`, or you can cast it to an `int` (which is like you're telling the compiler "trust me, it's going to be an `int` when the program is run") before you can treat it like an `int`.

Comment: I will re-read this a few times until I fully understand it. Thank you very much for the answer. I have fixed it now. Now I have to continue until I create a doubly linked list :) .